# Почему Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word document.Variables.Count == 0?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

У меня есть docx файл с переменными, которые я добавил через Экспресс блоки -> Поле... -> Автоматизация -> DocVariable. Там у меня несколько переменных (например FirstName, PageCount, StartDate и т.п.). Если нажать Alt + F9, то эти переменные отображаются.

Потом я использую Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word чтобы подставить в эти переменные значения. Почему-то `document.Variables.Count` у меня равен 0.

```
_appSource = new Application();
byte[] wordSourceContent = GetTemplateData(templateId, userId);
_tmpSourceFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "data", Path.GetRandomFileName());
var tmpFileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(_tmpSourceFile);
tmpFileStream.Write(wordSourceContent, 0, wordSourceContent.Length);
tmpFileStream.Close();
_documentSource = _appSource.Documents.Open(_tmpSourceFile);
if (_documentSource.Variables.Count != 0)
{
   var variable = _documentSource.Variables["Summary"];
   variable.Value = "TESTTESTTESTTESTTEST";
   _documentSource.Fields.Update();
   _appSource.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Код приведёте или прямо так будем ванговать?

Comment: Код добавил....

Answer (score 0):

Аналогично не смог понять, почему количество переменных=0.
Поэтому пошел на вот такое ухищрение:

```
object variable2 = e.Name;

if (sdoc.Variables.Count == 0)
  {                   
    Word.Variable var2 = sdoc.Variables.Add("FIO", ref variable2);
  }
else
  {
    sdoc.Variables["FIO"].Value = variable2.ToString();
  }

sdoc.Fields.Update();
```

Comment: А как быть если пользователи изначально создают шаблоны в Word, добавляют туда docVariables, а программа уже подставляет значения. В этом коде переменные добавляются программно в конец документа, правильно?

Comment: в том то и дело, что в шаблоне эти переменные уже были... но почему количество=0 я все еще не пойму...

Comment: Если вдруг разберетесь, то напишите пожалуйста.